# how do I enter the coordinates of a point in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I wan to give x,y,z coordinates to a point, for example to P point.
The P point coordinates are: P=(0,1,1)
How can I give the values in Matlab?

I tried P=(0,1,1) and Px=0 Py=0 Pz=0 ,but I need it to an equation.

Comment: I think you need a matlab tutorial, this is the first thing you learn in the first programming lesson.

Comment: Ok. Thanks the answer. But please, can give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one variable can store n-dimensional coordinates

```
P=[0 1 1];
```

you can also do this:

```
px=0;
py=1;
pz=1;
```